# Reading file in C++ error

Tags: c++, file-io, structure

I have a problem with reading a text file to structure with string. It just stops working and nothing can be done.

Structure:

```
struct Ksiazka
{
        string autor;
        string tytul;
        int data;
};
struct Ksiazka * d = new Ksiazka[10];
int il;


ofstream zapis("biblio.txt", ios::app);
                    for(int i = 0; i < il; i++)
                    {
                        zapis << d[i].autor << " ";
                        zapis << d[i].tytul << " ";
                        zapis << d[i].data;
                        if(i<il-1) zapis << " \n";
                    }
                    zapis.close();       
ifstream odczyt;
                odczyt.open("biblio.txt");
                odczyt.seekg(0);
                il = 0;
                while(!odczyt.eof())
                {
                    odczyt >> d[il].autor;
                    odczyt >> d[il].tytul;
                    odczyt >> d[il].data;
                    il++;
                }
                odczyt.close();
```

Comment: If you show no research effort, at least make sure you have a compilable, minimal testcase that reproduces the error. There's not even the declaration of `d` or `il`.

Comment: Also post a section of your data file.

Comment: The `>>` operator is for reading TEXT files. You seem to not be clear whether you want to read a text file or a binary file.

Comment: @PaulR data file will look something like this: 
name name title title year

Answer (score 0):

Use getline (odczyt,line);  and check what this cout << line << endl; gives before loading it into your struct

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are bitten by one of my pet-peeves with STL i/o streams: they are not typesafe.

If your author or title strings contains spaces (and most like they they do), when you are reading the lines, the << operators splits arguments on whitespace (space, tab, newline); so your code will simple read the first two **words**, not **strings**, followed by an attempt to read an integer. Imagine this is in your database:

`George Orwell 1984 1949`

Then after reading your author field would contain "George", the title "Orwell", and the year "1984". The next read will put "1949" in the author field...

Unfortunately, with STL there is no easy way to keep a string intact with the << and >> operators (especially if the string itself contains newlines). You might consider using base64 encoding/decoding, or urlencode/urldecode.

One last remarks: do not use a literal `"\n"`  to terminate a line, use std::endl.